# Buttons do not overlay over a canvas with a JS script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have recently started working with JS and its capabilities and I was trying to create a general menu that resembled something similar to a visual map (or if your prefer, a mindmap).

The visual map would be developed by different buttons (that link you with other pages that I still have to develop) displayed on the screen and in the background I would have a canvas that executes a JS script which draws the different lines that connect to every button onscreen, giving it then that "mindmap resemblance".

Here is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>
            TRIAL
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>
                TITLE
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="viewport">
            
            <button id="btn1">BUTTON 1</button>
            <button id="btn2">BUTTON 2</button>
            
            <canvas id="canvas" style="z-index:-1; position: absolute;">
                    <script>
                            var btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
                            var btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");
                
                            function getOffSet(el) {
                                const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                                return {
                                    x: rect.left,
                                    y: rect.top
                                };
                            }
                
                            var coord_btn1 = getOffSet(btn1);
                            var coord_btn2 = getOffSet(btn2);
                
                            function draw(btn_1_x,btn_1_y,btn_2_x,btn_2_y) {
                                const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
                
                                if (!canvas.getContext) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                
                                
                                ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                                ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                
                                
                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.moveTo(btn_1_x, btn_1_y);
                                ctx.lineTo(btn_2_x, btn_2_y);
                                ctx.stroke();
                
                            }
                            draw(coord_btn1.x,coord_btn1.y,coord_btn2.x,coord_btn2.y);
                            console.log("Coords BTN1: X–>" + coord_btn1.x + "; Y–>" + coord_btn1.y);
                            console.log("Coords BTN2: X–>" + coord_btn2.x + "; Y–>" + coord_btn2.y);
                       </script>
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the style.css file containing the buttons and some other things:

```
#btn1 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2; /*so as to overlay over z -1 canvas*/
    background-color: grey;

}
#btn2 {
    top: 150px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2; /*same for the second button*/
    background-color: grey;

}

.viewport {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem lies that when the line is drawn, it is below the two buttons (as I show with the uploaded picture). It gets even worse when you try to make the canvas to be the width of the page (`width: 100%;`). And the same problem still holds when adding new buttons in other places of the page.

[image]

I do not know how to fix it, but I think the JS is fine since I checked if it recorded the coordinates of both buttons in JS. And the functions for drawing the line seem to work when it is run alone, without any buttons, just adding some random coordinates. But it may be the case that there is something in the script that I forgot since I am new to JS.

For overlaying, the only way I know to do that is with the `z-index` property, but it does not seem to work.

For now, I am not worried with responsiveness of the webpage nor with the stylization of the buttons, I just want to get the buttons to be connected by the drawn line in the background.

If anyone knows which might be the mistake and if you have any suggestions as well for how to write JS script, would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help :) IDK.
refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

```js
const _canv = document.querySelector("canvas");
const _buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const _ctx = _canv.getContext("2d");

function scalCanv() {
  _canv.width = window.innerWidth;
  _canv.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function connButtons() {
  _buttons.forEach((button) => {
    _buttons.forEach((otherBtn) => {
      if (button != otherBtn) {
        _ctx.beginPath();
        _ctx.moveTo(button.offsetLeft + button.offsetWidth/2, button.offsetTop + button.offsetHeight/2);
        _ctx.lineTo(otherBtn.offsetLeft + otherBtn.offsetWidth/2, otherBtn.offsetTop + otherBtn.offsetHeight/2);
        _ctx.stroke();
      }
    });
  });
}

scalCanv();
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  scalCanv();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(connButtons);
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(connButtons);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: gray;
}

#btn-one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4vh;
  left: 40vw;
}

#btn-two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16vh;
  left: 16vw;
}

#btn-tre {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 10vw;
}

#btn-for {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="btn-one">one</button>
  <button id="btn-two">two</button>
  <button id="btn-tre">tre</button>
  <button id="btn-for">for</button>
  <canvas></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).